# SQL Alchemy ResultProxy.rowcount should not be zero

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, rowcount

Does anyone know how to get the row count from an SQL Alchemy query ResultProxy object without looping through the result set? The ResultProxy.rowcount attribute shows 0, I would expect it to have a value of 2. For updates it shows the number of rows affected which is what I would expect.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine(
    'oracle+cx_oracle://user:pass@host:port/database'
    )

session = sessionmaker(
    bind = engine
    , autocommit = False
    , autoflush = False
    )()

sql_text = u"""
    SELECT 1 AS Val FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS Val FROM dual
    """

results = session.execute(sql_text)

print '%s rows returned by query...\n' % results.rowcount
print results.keys()

for i in results:
    print repr(i)
```

Output:

```
0 rows returned by query...

[u'val']
(1,)
(2,)
```

Answer (score 32):

resultproxy.rowcount is ultimately a proxy for the DBAPI attribute cursor.rowcount.    Most DBAPIs do not provide the "count of rows" for a SELECT query via this attribute; its primary purpose is to provide the number of rows matched by an UPDATE or DELETE statement.   A relational database in fact does not know how many rows would be returned by a particular statement until it has finished locating all of those rows; many DBAPI implementations will begin returning rows as the database finds them, without buffering, so no such count is even available in those cases.

To get the count of rows a SELECT query would return, you either need to do a SELECT COUNT(*) up front, or you need to fetch all the rows into an array and perform len() on the array.

The notes at ResultProxy.rowcount discuss this further (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html?highlight=rowcount#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy.rowcount):

> Notes regarding ResultProxy.rowcount:
>
> - This attribute returns the number of rows matched, which is not necessarily the same as the number of rows that were actually modified - an UPDATE statement, for example, may have no net change on a given row if the SET values given are the same as those present in the row
>     already. Such a row would be matched but not modified. On backends
>     that feature both styles, such as MySQL, rowcount is configured by
>     default to return the match count in all cases.
> - ResultProxy.rowcount is *only* useful in conjunction with an UPDATE or DELETE statement. Contrary to what the Python DBAPI says, it does
>     not return the number of rows available from the results of a SELECT
>     statement as DBAPIs cannot support this functionality when rows are
>     unbuffered.
> - ResultProxy.rowcount may not be fully implemented by all dialects. In particular, most DBAPIs do not support an aggregate rowcount result
>     from an executemany call. The ResultProxy.supports_sane_rowcount() and ResultProxy.supports_sane_multi_rowcount() methods will report from
>     the dialect if each usage is known to be supported.
> - Statements that use RETURNING may not return a correct rowcount.

Answer (score 3):

You could use this:

```
rowcount = len(results._saved_cursor._result.rows)
```

Then your code will be

```
print '%s rows returned by query...\n' % rowcount
print results.keys()
```

**Only tested 'find' queries**

It works for me.

Comment: This also worked for me and wish I found this sooner! Thanks!