# Get the `.rowcount` of SQLAlchemy ORM query

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

## How do I get both the `rowcount` and the instances of an SQLAlchemy ORM [`Query`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query) in a single roundtrip to the database?

If I call `query.all()`, I get a standard list, which I can get the `len()` of, but that requires loading the whole resultset in memory at once.

If I call `iter(query)`, I get back a standard python generator, with no access to the `.rowcount` of the underlying `ResultProxy`.

If I call `query.count()` then `iter(query)` I'm doing two roundtrips of a potentially expensive query to the database.

if I managed to get hold of a `ResultProxy` for a `Query`, that would give me the `.rowcount`, then I could use `Query.instances()` to get the same generator that `Query.__iter__()` would give me.

But is there a convenient way of getting at the `ResultProxy` of a `Query` other than repeating what `Query.__iter__()` and `Query._execute_and_instances()` do? Seems rather inconvenient.

## Notice

As mentioned by [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13150615/1273938) (thanks [@terminus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5051310/terminus)), getting the `ResultProxy.rowcount` might or might not be useful, and is explicitly warned against in SQLAlchemy documentation for pure "select" statements.

That said, in the case of `psycopg2`, the `.rowcount` of the underlying cursor is [documented to return the correct number of records](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.rowcount) returned by any query, even "`SELECT`" queries, [unless you're using the `stream_results=True` option](https://blog.rectalogic.com/2017/04/sqlalchemy-psycopg2-streaming-rowcount.html) (thanks [@SuperShoot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6560549/supershoot)).

Comment: [Maybe useful info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145068/sql-alchemy-resultproxy-rowcount-should-not-be-zero).

Comment: Found this blog which I think does what you are after: https://blog.rectalogic.com/2017/04/sqlalchemy-psycopg2-streaming-rowcount.html

Comment: @SuperShoot, thanks, but that blog post is only showing how to use the standard SQLAlchemy query mechanism, not the ORM query mechanism, while using streaming results AND getting the right rowcount. It's really interesting, but not what I'm after.