# In SQLAlchemy, how can I get affected rows after update using optimistic lock?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have known that in a session of SQLAlchemy, `update()` will not work, maybe even not communicate with database until you use `session.commit`.

Here is my code, I think the skill I use is called `optimistic lock`:

```
with Session() as session:
    # get one record
    object = session.query(Table).where(key=param).limit(1)
    
    content = "here is the calculated value of my business"

    # update the record by the id of the gotten record 
    # if 2 thread get the same record and run into this update statement, I think only can success
    # because it is ensured by the MySQL MVCC
    Table.update(Table).set(Table.content = content).where(id = object.id)
    sessoin.commit()
```

But I hava a question here, what if I want to do something `in the thread which got the lock` after `session.commit()`?

For example, the code I expect is like this:

```
affected_rows = sessoin.commit()
if affected_rows:
    do_something_after_get_lock_success()
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

According to the docs, `ResultProxy` has a property `rowcount`. you can get the affected rows from that.

but note that :

> This attribute returns the number of rows matched, which is not necessarily the same as the number of rows that were actually modified - an UPDATE statement, for example, may have no net change on a given row if the SET values given are the same as those present in the row already. Such a row would be matched but not modified. On backends that feature both styles, such as MySQL, rowcount is configured by default to return the match count in all cases.

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145068/sql-alchemy-resultproxy-rowcount-should-not-be-zero) also for great Mike Bayer explanation about this.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I get the `ResultProxy`? In a session, the `session.update()` only returns a long, which is dirty. The `session.commit` returns nothing.