# How can I get the number of results associated with a sqlalchemy result proxy object before fetching the results?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, sqlalchemy

I'm currently trying to figure out how to check how many results are associated to the result proxy as I query my database. However the method **rowcount** associated to the result proxy object wields a result I can't make sense:

```
import sqlalchemy as sql

# Creating the query.
s = sql.select([Observations.timestamp_dt]).where(Observations.ar_id == 2)

# Assuming that the session was already started, execute the statement.
rp = session.execute(s)

# Using rowcount.
rp.rowcount

>>> -1
```

Then I had a check for information that could be useful and found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145068/sql-alchemy-resultproxy-rowcount-should-not-be-zero) that is similar. However, when I tried to implement the proposed solution I got an error:

```
# Checking how many rows are associated with rp.
rowcount = len(rp._saved_cursor._result.rows)

>>> AttributeError: 'sqlite3.Cursor' object has no attribute '_result'
```

The **help()** function or the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html) didn't really provided information I could use to get the number of rows that this result proxy object have. I also tried:

```
rp._saved_cursor.rowcount
>>> -1

rp._saved_cursor.lastrowid
>>> 0
```

Which is not helpful giving that I need to know how many times I will need to go over this object.

The reason why I would like to know the amount of results beforehand is so I can know for how many frames, and therefore times which **rp.fetchone()** will be used, to feed images into matplotlib **FuncAnimation**. I'm looking for the number to assign to the **frames** argument on the code below:

```
def and_animation(ar_id, tstart, tstop):
    # Making the session.
    session = sup_unit.mainsession()

    # Loading the mock data with the correct dimensions.
    s = sql.select([ActiveRegion.columnshape, ActiveRegion.rowshape]).where(ActiveRegion.AR_id == ar_id)

    dimensions = session.execute(s).fetchone()

    # Load the data here.
    s = sql.select([Observations.timestamp_dt, Observations.d4vm_vz]).where(sql.and_(Observations.ar_id == ar_id,
                                                                                     Observations.timestamp_int > tstart,
                                                                                     Observations.timestamp_int < tstop))

    rp = session.execute(s)
    files = rp.fetchall()

    # Creating the figure objects.
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,8))

    # Creating an image to start.
    img = plt.imshow(ajuste(files[0][1], dimensions[0]), origin='lower', 
                     cmap='RdBu',
                     vmax=1,vmin=-1 ,animated=True)
    plt.colorbar(shrink=0.75)



    def refresher(frame_number, img, files):
        # Preparing the new data
        new_data = ajuste(files[frame_number+1][1], dimensions[0])

        #setting the new data
        img.set_data(new_data)
        plt.title(f'{files[frame_number][0]}')

        return(img,)



    ani = FuncAnimation(fig, refresher,
                        frames=range(len(files)-1), blit=True,
                        fargs = [img, files])
    ani.save("vz.mp4")
    #plt.show()
    return
```

This way instead of using a **rp.fetchall()** I can take one image per interaction preventing the process to use swap memory or even crashing if the number of images is too large.

Thanks.

Comment: You query could be wrong and you are not getting any records because of it.

Comment: I don't think so because I can just go using fetchone() and the results pop out.

Comment: have you tried `.count()`?

Comment: rp.count() returned me >>> AttributeError: 'ResultProxy' object has no attribute 'count'

Comment: In that case you will need to do `len(rp.fetchall())`.

Comment: Because rowcount only returns rows for delete and update according to the docs.

Comment: You read the wrong answer from the question you linked to. The accepted answer is the answer to your question as well, not just similar: "A relational database in fact does not know how many rows would be returned by a particular statement until it has finished locating all of those rows; many DBAPI implementations will begin returning rows as the database finds them, without buffering, so no such count is even available in those cases.". The one you tried to use is specific to some driver implementation, though it is not mentioned to which.

Comment: Correction, the top voted, not accepted. And the proposed solution likely works with cx_oracle.

Comment: So there's no way I can get the record size to iterate over them fetching one image at time to produce a movie? I need the number of frames to do so. Because if I actually use len(rp.fetchall()) that process will discard the rp and also take a lot of time isn't that correct?

Comment: If you'd rewrite your question to address that problem ("I need the count of frames beforehand" instead of cursor rowcount in SELECT), it'd no longer be a duplicate (of the linked post). And you'd store the result list of `rp.fetchall()` first, then take its `len()`.

Comment: Ah thanks for placing me on the right direction. I was actually afraid of overcomplicating things by overstating the problem. I will edit the post as you sugested and make an example with the application I need it.

Comment: @IljaEverilä if I store the result of rp.fetchall() and take it's len() this surely address the problem but then I suppose that to avoid memory shortage I should query for something other than the images, like the timestamps, that are in the same table and occupy much less space in memory and then do the test. I was wondering if it is possible to know this amount by inspecting the result proxy so I could jump this step.